# Find the set of values of $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=ax^2+x$ and $g(x)=\ln(1+x)$ have a common tangent in a common point.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

With $a \in \mathbb{R}$, consider the following two functions:

$$f, g : (-1, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

$$f(x) = ax^2+x \hspace{2cm} g(x) = \ln(1 + x)$$

I have to find the set of values of $a$ such that the functions $f$ and $g$ have a common tangent in a common point.

I know that to find the common point of $2$ functions, we must solve:

$$f(x) = g(x)$$

And I think that for $2$ functions to have a common tangent, we should have:

$$f'(x) = g'(x)$$

So if we wanted both, meaning a common tangent **in** a common point, we should solve the system:

$$\begin{cases} f(x) = g(x) \\ f'(x) = g'(x) \end{cases}$$

I am not sure at all if what I've done so far is right or wrong. If my reasoning is incorrect, please tell me. Anyway, I proceeded with the system:

$$\begin{cases} ax^2+x=\ln(1+x)  \\2ax+1=\dfrac{1}{1+x} \end{cases}$$

Since $x \in (-1, \infty)$ we can multiply the second equation by $1+x$.

$$\begin{cases} ax^2+x - \ln(1+x) = 0  \\ 2ax^2+2ax+x+1=0 \end{cases}$$

And I got stuck here. I don't know how to solve that system (provided that what I did so far is right and that this system is really what I have to solve). So, how can I find the values of $a$ such that $f$ and $g$ have a common tangent in a common point?

Comment: Use the quadratic formula on both equations and set the term inside the square root $\ge0$, then take the intersection.

Comment: The second equation is quadratic in $x$ and will have at most two solutions. Then it remains to check for which $a$ any of these solutions can satisfy the first equation.

Comment: You can solve for $x$ in terms of $a$ in the second equation and plug the solution in the first equation. After that, you can use calculus to describe the solution of the resulting first equation.

Comment: @Thorgott There will be at most $2$ x's, but I have to find the set of values of $a$, not $x$ and there are a lot of values of $a$ for which that equation has solutions.

Comment: Yes, but you have two equations. Reread my second sentence or Mustafa's comment.

Comment: @Thorgott You said "Then it remains to check for which $a$ any of these solutions can satisfy the first equation". Well, that's where my problem is :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your second equation, i.e. after multiplication by $1+x$, we have:
$$2ax^2 + 2ax + 1 + x = 1, \quad \text{right?}$$

If so, then your second equation is equivalent with:
$$2ax^2 + 2ax + 1 + x = 1 \iff 2ax^2 + 2ax + x = 0,$$

what is easy to solve:
$$x_1=0, x_2=-1-\frac{1}{2a}.$$

Solution $x_1=0$ satisfy your first equation **for each** $a \in \mathbb{R}$, and solution $x_2=-1-\frac{1}{2a}$ will yield to
$$e^{a^2 - \frac{1}{4a}} = -\frac{1}{2a},$$

so it is obvious that we have to exclude $a=0$ fom set of solutions. Next, in our last equation the term on right side is always positive, and the term on left side is a line parallel with $x$ axis, so we have to exclude all values for $a$ that give negative number on the left side of that equation (a line bellow $x$ axis). In other words, only negative values for $a$ will be acceptable for the set of solutions...

Answer (score 0):

Solving the second (quadratic) equation you obtain:
$$x_1=-\frac a 2\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;x_2=-1$$
The second solution must be discarded since $\,\log(1-1)\,$ is not defined.

Substituting the first solution in the other equation, gives the following equation that can be solved only with numerical methods:
$$a=2(1-e^{a(a^2-2)/4})\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$

Anyway, the equation $\,(1)\,$ has also the simple solution $\,a=0$.

Actually, $\,f(x)=x\,$ and $\,g(x)=\ln(1+x)\,$ have a common tangent ($f(x)=x$) in $\,x=0$.